# Как ожидать сообщения 2 пользователей aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Как "связать" двух пользователей? Допустим есть бот, который после команды старт отвечает "Попросите второго пользователя зайти в бота и написать /code {code}", и когда второй пользователь вводит команду `/code {code}` первому пользователю приходило сообщение "{user.id} ввёл этот код"? Сам код будет генерироваться с помощью `random.choice()` из листа слов, пример: "loremipsum", "randomtext" и т.п.. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [Deep-linking](https://core.telegram.org/api/links#bot-links):

> `t.me/<bot_username>?start=<parameter>`

Выдайте первому пользователю ссылку с доп параметром: `t.me/namebot?start=123456`, которую он передаст второму пользователю.

Когда второй пользователь перейдет по это ссылке, и нажмет кнопу `Старт`, боту будет передана команда `/start 123456`

И делайте то, что необходимо:

```
@router.message(CommandStart())
async def handler(message: Message, command: CommandObject, bot: Bot):
    if command.args:
        first_user_id = await db.first_user_id(command.args) # тут нужно получить откуда-нибудь id первого пользователя (предполагаю, что он хранится в БД и был записан ранее, при выдаче ссылки первому пользователю), либо сразу передавать id первого пользователя в параметре
        await bot.send_message(first_user_id, f"{first_user_id} ввёл этот код")
```

Примерно так. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил

UPD:
Если передавать аргумент не с командой /start, а другой, то будет немного отличаться:

```
@dp.message(Command("code"))
async def cmd_settimer(message: Message, command: CommandObject, bot: Bot):
    arg = command.args
```

Это для команды вида `/code {code}`

UPD Для aiogram 2 можно так сделать:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="code")
async def coord(message: types.Message):
    arg = message.get_full_command()[1].split(' ')
    await message.answer(arg)
```

Comment: Спасибо, можно еще вопрос? Чтобы изменить нужный код нужно написать if command.args == 123? И получиться ли таким образом делать ссылки со сгенерированным случайно кодом? Можно ли вместо "ComandStart" написать "commands='code'", чтобы писать /code 123?

Comment: @Zailox нет, так изменить код нельзя. if command.args проверяет на существование аргумента. А код можно менять при выдачи ссылки. Аргумент можно сделать любой, главное связать его с первым пользователем, что бы знать куда отправлять сообщение, поле перехода по такой ссылке вторым пользователем. Опишите вашу задачу подробнее, скорректировав вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, отредактировал.

Comment: @Zailox дополнил ответ

Comment: Это аиограм версии 3 (просто у меня версии 2)? Просто бот не отвечает на команду /code, написал так::   ```@dp.message(Command("code"))
async def cmd_settimer(message: Message, command: CommandObject, bot: Bot):
    arg = command.args
    if arg == 1234:
        await message.answer("test")```                                    Или нужно по другому?

Comment: @Zailox да, я писал для aiogram 3, дополнил ответ для aiogram 2

Comment: Странно, даже в стр перевёл, но бот молчит, и принт в консоль ничего не выводит, я как понял этот код - это замена этого?

```msg = message.text.replace('/command ', '')```